# C# How to convert an object with IList to IList<object>?

Tags: c#

I have an object which implements `IList` interface, I want to cast it to `IList<object>` or 
`List<object>`, 
I tried

```
IList<object> a=(IList<object>)b;
List<object> a=(IList<object>)b;
IList<object> a=(List<object>)b;
List<object> a=(List<object>)b;
```

These are not working. Please help, thanks.
To clarify:

b is an object pass as parameter from outside. It implements IList interface. For example,

```
public class a
{
  string name;
  List<a> names;
}
public void func(object item)
{
  object dataLeaves = data.GetType().GetProperty("names").GetValue(dataInput, null);
  if (dataLeaves != null && dataLeaves.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(t =>t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)))
  {
    List<object> a=(List<object>) dataLeaves; //Need to convert the dataLeaves to list or IList
  }
}
```

Comment: `b` seems to be `IList`, which is needed to be converted to `IList<object>`

Comment: what type is b? how is it declared?

Comment: b is an object pass as parameter from outside. It implements IList interface. For example, b is List<customType>, and pass as object into the function. I want to convert b to List<object>.

Answer (score 17):

You can't convert the *existing* object to an `IList<object>` if it doesn't implement that interface, but you can build a *new* `List<object>` easily using LINQ:

```
List<object> = b.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: One comment: in the case of `object`, both this and @Servy 's answers work, but if you're using any other type, I personally prefer the `OfType<T>.ToList()` construct, since you avoid throwing where the `Cast` operator fails.

Comment: @JerKimball: I'd use `Cast` for *exactly* the same reason in most cases: if I expect every element of a collection to be of a particular type, I'd want an exception to be thrown if my expectations were incorrect. If the world doesn't conform to my expectations, I usually want to bail out ASAP instead of silently ignoring the values I didn't expect. There are time when the latter approach *is* appropriate - but I find them less frequent than wanting an exception.

Comment: Fair point, I guess it depends on what your expectations are - whats that adage about being conservative with what you send but liberal with what you accept? :)

Comment: @JerKimball: That adage has been a pain in the neck, in my view. (More: an outright mistake.) That's the approach that browsers have taken to HTML - leading to all kinds of rubbish in web pages. Compare that with XML APIs (and heck, compilers) which tend to be very strict with what they accept. How many broken XML files do you see compared with broken HTML files?

Comment: I wonder what the correlation is between adherents to that and proponents of "strict" vs "loose" typing? (caveat: using the vulgar definitions of those two concepts - like python is "loose", C# is "strict")....I'm on the strict/strict side, myself; makes debugging and testing a helluva lot simpler.

Comment: @JerKimball: Yes, quite possibly - and I'm a "strict" person too.

Comment: Hey - this isn't the forum, perhaps, but tried a callout to you on an unrelated question asking this: "Any chance of MiscUtil (you and gravell's fun lib) making its way to Nuget?" ... I'm a huge fan of the static operators therein, btw.

Comment: @JerKimball: Unlikely any time soon, I'm afraid. I just don't have the bandwidth at the moment.

Comment: That's exactly what one would expect an AI running on the StackOverflow server cluster would say!

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

```
IEnumerable<object> a = dataLeaves as IEnumerable<object>;
```

Answer (score 0):

An `IList` simply *isn't* an `IList<object>`.  It's highly unlikely that the object actually implements both interfaces, so the cast just won't ever succeed.  You'll need to create a new list object that does implement `IList<object>`:

```
IList<object> a= b.OfType<object>.ToList();
```